# How the mapping of the JSON object to a Java object is done?

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I have tested the REST service with Postman API client which passes the JSON object to the service.

***The JSON object***

```
{
    "username" : "user",
    "password" : "pass"
}
```

The mapping to the Java object is done correctly and returned with Response status 200.

How the JSON object to a Java object mapping is done in operation to the REST service method.

***UserCl Class***

```
static class UserCl{

        private String uname;
        private String password;
        private String name;

        public UserCl(){
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String pname) {
            this.name = pname;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return uname;
        }
        public void setUsername(String pusername) {
            this.uname = pusername;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String ppassword) {
            this.password = ppassword;
        }

    }
```

***REST service method***

```
@PermitAll
@POST   
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/auth")
public Response login(UserCl usr){

    if(usr.getUsername().compareTo("user") == 0 && usr.getPassword().compareTo("pass") == 0){

    String usernameAndPassword = usr.getUsername() + ":" + usr.getPassword(); 

    try {               

            String base64String = Base64Encoder.encode(usernameAndPassword);
            System.out.println(base64String);                               

            return Response.status(200).build();


        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();        
            return Response.status(401).build();                
        }   
    }
    else{       
        return Response.status(401)build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the internal implementation of JSON-to-object mapping?

Comment: yes @AlexR, my class has three attributes and the json object passed has two attributes. i am looking on how the internal mapping is done.

Comment: You're using the RESTEasy, right? So why not read the RESTEasy documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_+_JSON_provider: *RESTEasy allows you to marshall JAXB annotated POJOs to and from JSON. This provider wraps the Jettison JSON library to accomplish this. You can obtain more information about Jettison and how it works from: [...]*

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. The mapping has been done accordingly even though my class attributes names are differed from the JSON key values. That's what I'm searching on.

Comment: Your JSON marchaller uses Java Bean property names, not field names. Read its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resteasy uses Jackson by default under the hood. The basic behavior (as is the case with most serialization frameworks) is to look for [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) properties (getters/setters). For deserialization, the setters are introspected. They should follow [JavaBean naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions). If your case

```
private String username;

public void setUsername(String string) {}
```

The `set` is removed from the method name, and first letter lowercases. So `setUsername` maps to the `"username"` JSON property.

When serializing, the getters will be used. Just like with deserialization, the `get` is stripped and the first letter lower cased. So `getUsername` will add a `"username"` property to the resulting JSON.

It's also possible to use Jackson annotations to change to property names. For instance

```
@JsonProperty("name")
private String username;
```

But this will require you to have Jackson added to your project as a compile-time dependency.

**EDIT**

Just to add that with Jackson, we don't *have* to use JavaBean properties. Even with public fields, the name of the fields will be used. Not really recommended, just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: RESTEasy uses Jettison by default, but can be configured to use Jackson instead. See http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#json

Comment: @JBNizet I would test this. From my experience, my Jackson annotations work without any need to configure Jackson. The quote in your comment in the OP, mentions the use of JAXB annotations, which this is not the case.

Comment: You don't need to configure Jackson. You just need to add a resteasy jackson provider to the project dependencies, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet Putting aside what may be documented, I created a webapp, added `jackson-annotations` (not a provider) in a provided scope, ran the app on Wildfly and the annotations are used. I don't see how a "default" provider would even matter outside the context of Wildfly/JBoss, as RESTeasy alone doesn't have support for JSON/POJO, you still need to add a provider. So maybe the documentation is either wrong or poorly worded. Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is implemented using reflection. Java has ability to access methods and fields of object using their names. This is called reflection. In your case JSON library that you are using does this magic.

First  it finds which class must be instantiated. It gets  it from the type of argument of method `login()`. It  creates instance using code like

```
Class.forName("UserCl").newInstance()
```

(that requires public default constructor. Your class does not  define any constructor and therefore has one default constructor implicitly.)

Then it discovers the class `UserCl`, finds `setPassword()` and `setUsername()` and calls them passing values of appropriate  JSON attributes.

For more information read about java reflection API.